# How to keep values occur only in one group?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am working on a dataframe likes:

```
groups .  values
a .        1
a .        1
a          2
b .        2
b .        3
b .        3
c .        4
c .        5
c .        6
d .        6
d .        7
d .        2
```

The problem is to turn it into something like:

```
groups .  values
a .        1
a .        1
b .        3
b .        3
c .        4
c .        5
d .        7
```

I want to keep rows whose values only occur in ONE group. For example, value 2 is deleted because it occurs in three different groups, but value 1 is kept although it occur twice in ONLY ONE group.

Is there any functions from dplyr package can handle this problem? or I have to write my own function?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have tried something like "DATAFRAME %>% group_by(groups) %>% distinct(values)", but it only keeps the unique values in each groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked for a `dplyr` solution:

```
df %>% group_by(values) %>% filter(n_distinct(groups) == 1)
# # A tibble: 7 x 2
# # Groups:   values [5]
# groups values
# <chr>   <int>
#1 a           1
#2 a           1
#3 b           3
#4 b           3
#5 c           4
#6 c           5
#7 d           7
```

with

```
df <- structure(list(groups = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d"),
                     values = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 2L)),
                row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by `values` and see if column `groups` has only one element. This can be done with `ave`.

```
i <- as.logical(with(df1, ave(as.numeric(groups), values, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)))
df1[i, ]
#   groups values
#1       a      1
#2       a      1
#5       b      3
#6       b      3
#7       c      4
#8       c      5
#11      d      7
```

**Data in `dput` format.**

```
df1 <-
structure(list(groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d"), class = "factor"), values = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 2L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x[x$values %in% names(which(colSums(table(x)>0)==1)),]
```

where

```
x = structure(list(groups = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
  "c", "c", "d", "d", "d"), values = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

or, a `data.table` solution:

```
setDT(x)[, .SD[uniqueN(groups)==1], values]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sqldf` package for your original data frame `df`:

```
library(sqldf)
result <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df
                 WHERE `values` IN (
                     SELECT `values` from (
                         SELECT `values`, groups, count(*) as num from df
                         GROUP BY `values`, groups) t
                      GROUP BY `values` 
                      HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
                 )")
```